# STL Model looks nothing like Blender Model when exported

Tags: modeling, export, stl

I made a few 3D parts in Blender to print them out for a project, and yes, they're very small in size as seen below:

[image: Blender model]

However, when exported as an STL it is nothing alike:

[image: Exported STL model]

Is this because the size is too small to export properly or does the issue lie elsewhere?

Comment: Apply the scale to the objects (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) and try exporting again.

Comment: Ahh right, I forgot about that. thank you!